# Background reveal javascript not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery

By following this tutorial :https://codepen.io/xaviDDB/pen/ExaKeeN I made a section in my website with this background reveal. here is the link:http://example.com/abra/
The code works fine if I do not have any other section in this page. But if I do, then it gets very strange. The reveal circle move away from the Mouse. See the page, I have added a horse image & the code gets messy. How do I solve this?

This is my current code:

```js
(function() {

  let magic = document.querySelector('.magic');
  let magicWHalf = magic.offsetWidth / 2;

  document.body.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e) {
    magic.style.left = e.pageX - magicWHalf + 'px';
    magic.style.top = e.pageY - magicWHalf + 'px';
  });

  document.body.addEventListener('mouseout', function(e) {
    //magic.style.left = 'calc(50% - 10rem)';
    //magic.style.top = 'calc(50% - 10rem)';
  });

})();
```

```css
.containers {
  position: relative;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 1;
}

.containers:hover {
  cursor: crosshair;
}

.text {
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 72px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  color: #000000;
  bottom: 20%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 3;
}

.magic {
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(50% - 10rem);
  left: calc(50% - 10rem);
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  background: center center no-repeat fixed;
  background-size: cover;
  border-radius: 50%;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="containers">
  <div class="text">Lorem Ipsum</div>
  <div class="magic" style="background-image: url('https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/142996/hover-reveal.jpg')"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please put the non-working code in the snippet here, not at another site.

Comment: the code I added is the one not working. My mouse gets far away if I add any section in my page with this code.

Comment: Please add the extra content that makes it misbehave, it looks like it's working.

Comment: I can't see the problem when I use `Run code snippet` here.

Comment: for example if I add another <div>...more content</div> above it, then it does not work properly anymore. The mouse gets far away. you can check the issue here: http://steedtoken.com/abra/

Comment: If you have two elements with `class="magic"` then `let magic = document.querySelector('.magic');` will only return the first element that matches and all subsequent code is assuming there is a single element. Your example should better illustrate the problem

Comment: @JonP but I do not have two elements with magic class. Only one.

Comment: Well, we're guessing because you have only provided half the code here. Don't make us go elsewhere, provide a [MCVE] here.

Comment: @JonP, ok I have added similar coding here also. Please see my updated code here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to update your mouse-move function in javascript. It has to calculate the relative mouse position to its parent (.container)

and one more improvement: set the eventListener on the element you want to hover. Not the entire body.

```js
    (function() {

  const container = document.querySelector('.container');
  const magic = document.querySelector('.magic');
  const magicWHalf = magic.offsetWidth / 2;
  
  container.addEventListener('mousemove',function(e){
    const rect = container.getBoundingClientRect(),
    scrollLeft = window.pageXOffset || document.documentElement.scrollLeft,
    scrollTop = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
    
    magic.style.left = (e.pageX - (rect.left + scrollLeft)) - magicWHalf+'px';
    magic.style.top = (e.pageY - (rect.top + scrollTop)) - magicWHalf+'px';
  });

  container.addEventListener('mouseout',function(e){
    //magic.style.left = 'calc(50% - 10rem)';
    //magic.style.top = 'calc(50% - 10rem)';
  });

})();
```

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 1;
}
.container:hover {
  cursor: crosshair;
}
.text {
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 72px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  color: #000000;
  bottom: 20%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 3;
}
.magic {
  --size: 20rem;
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(50% - var(--size));
  left: calc(50% - var(--size));
  width: var(--size);
  height: var(--size);
  background: center no-repeat fixed;
  background-size: cover;
  border-radius: 50%;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<h1>add</h1>
<h1>extra</h1>
<h1>space</h1>
<h1>at top</h1>
<div class="container">
  <div class="text">Lorem Ipsum</div>
  <div class="magic" style="background-image: url('https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/142996/hover-reveal.jpg')"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: if I have another section above it, it does not work: check please: https://steedtoken.com/abra/

Comment: Did you updated the javascript code?

Comment: Yes exactly same code have been used from your snippet.

Comment: @user2802110 i updated the javascript, can you try again?

Comment: you are absolutely legend. it SOLVED!!!! Can not thank you enough mate. great job done. Have a good day!

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the *height* of the previous element of your *div.container*

html

```
<div class="other">Other div </div>
<div class="container">
 <div class="text">Lorem Ipsum</div>
 <div class="magic" style="background-image: url('https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/142996/hover-reveal.jpg')"></div>
</div>
```

js

```
  let magic = document.querySelector('.magic');
  let magicWHalf = magic.offsetWidth / 2;
  let heightPrevELm=document.querySelector('.other').offsetHeight;
  
  document.body.addEventListener('mousemove',function(e){
   magic.style.left = e.pageX - magicWHalf+'px';
   magic.style.top = e.pageY - (magicWHalf+heightPrevELm)+'px';
  });
```

You can see the result here :
https://codepen.io/bertyn99/pen/YzEwOpO

But i think if they are multiple element before we need to optimize the code

Comment: Yes there are at least 4/5 section before it.

Comment: Yes I checked your code. If I increase the other div say like 400vh, the height of that other section increase & it is the same problem again.